# set up (VirtualBox + CentOS) with (nginx + PHP + MySql) on MacOS

Tags: centos, nginx, macos, virtualbox, port-forwarding

I'm trying to set up   (Virtual Box + CentOS)  with (nginx + PHP + MySql) on MacOS, the future I can coding on MacOS then throw file to the share folder with (Virtual Box + CentOS) and execute on (nginx + PHP + MySql).

But I have problem I can make browser on MacOS read the file direction, I do find the keyword like port forwarding but still not work.

I did below step to install

**install CentOS and setting config**
1. install CentOS minimal version
2. after installed CentOS, `ifconfig eth0` `dhclient eth0` `ifconfig eth0`
3. edit file
`vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`
change some line

```
ONBOOT="yes"  
MM_Controlled="no"  
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
```

4. restart network `service network restart`

**install (nginx + PHP + MySql)**
5. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-centos-6

**setting Port Forwarding**
6. in VirtualBox app click Setting on toolbar > click Network > click Port Forwarding
fill

```
Name >>>> Protocol >>>> Host IP >>>> Host Port >>>> Guest IP >>>> Guest Port  
CentOS >>>> TCP >>>> 170.20.10.2 >>>> 8080 >>>> 10.0.2.15 >>>> 80
```

after I type `170.20.10.2:8080/info.php` nothing respond.
Did I miss something ??

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I see `170.20.10.2:1000/info.php` in Safari. Are you sure it's not redirecting?

Comment: it only shows can't open the page  … isn't responding

Comment: did I miss some steps? it just set in virtual box setting not need to do anything more?

Answer (score 0):

Its working for me on  these options  :

[Port forwarding settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gl33v.png)

Browser photo :

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGniZ.png)

Comment: Can you give a description of what's in the image as they can't always be ensured to exist in the future.